# MailApp.sendEmail is not working properly

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a notification using `MailApp.sendEmail` on editing a google spreadsheet (even on addition of new row or editing existing data)

Here is the code I wrote:

```
function onEdit(e) {    
    var emailId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).getValues();
    var desc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getLastRow(), 5, 1, 1).getValues();
    var guid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getLastRow(), 6, 1, 1).getValues();
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailId, guid, guid);
    // Browser.msgBox(emailId + guid);
}
```

This code is extracting the edited data which I can see using `Browser.msgBox(emailId + guid);` (but only if placed before the `MailApp.sendEmail` and not if placed after MailApp.sendEmail function). When I use `MailApp.sendEmail` function with some other function, it executes well and is sending the mails too. But not in this function.

Any help or pointers to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The special `onEdit()` trigger function is called a Simple Trigger. Check the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).

> (Simple Triggers) cannot access any services that require authentication as that user. For example, the Google Translate service is anonymous and can be accessed by the simple triggers. Google Calendar, Gmail, and Sites are not anonymous and the simple triggers cannot access those services.